# How do you resolve the error "unexpected '_592_000'" in /vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/Common.php

Tags: codeigniter-4

I have installed and completed the project on codeigniter 4.2.1, but after making it live on cpanel I am facing the issue

> Fatal error "unexpected '_592_000'"  in /vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/Common.php

what can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I upgraded the PHP version from 7.4 to php v8.1 and the error is gone